# How to delete multiple string values in firebird sql?

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to delete the rows with string values as described below. When I run the query it deletes only the rows with the first value.

```
select 
    column1,
    column2
from table
where column1 = 2 and
    column2 = ('value1''value2''value3');
```

Comment: Hint:  `column2 in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a newbie in sql and easily forgot for IN operator. Thanks again. This helped.